# How to push Sitecore Application logs to Azure Storage?

Tags: paas

Need help to configure the Application logs in `Azure` storage, the below Sitecore Environment.

Version: `Sitecore 9.3 Azure PaaS`

Monitoring: `New Relic`.

Application logs are currently available in the Sitecore app service FileSystem - `App_Data\logs folder`.

What is working ? Able to configure the Diagnostic setting and push the app service metrics into Azure storage.

How to configure and store the application logs in the Azure Storage instead of the App Service filesystem. Can app-service can auto upload to Azure Storage or we need to customize the log4net logs to push application logs to Storage ?

Comment: You can use power shell to push logs from azure web app to azure storage.

Comment: Is there any automated approach for this ?

Comment: I don’t think so.